# SQLServer: Problem with Construction SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I'm having some problems with executing an SQL Query using VBScript.

I have a table A with a primary key (K_ID) referenced as a foreign key (FK_ID) in another table B.

Usually I want to retrieve all the information in the B table for the oldest K_ID using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE FK_ID in (SELECT TOP 1 K_ID FROM A WHERE USED <> 'Y' AND ENV = 'XXX' ORDER BY K_ID)
```

The above works just fine.

What I'm trying to do now is retrieving the information for the second oldest K_ID and I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE FK_ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 K_ID FROM (SELECT TOP 2 K_ID FROM A WHERE USED <> 'Y' AND ENV = 'XXX' ORDER BY K_ID ) z ORDER BY K_ID DESC)
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, this query runs just fine and I get the answer I need.

Now if I try the same query using VBS and ADODB.Connection, I get the following error message:
**ORA-00923: mot-clé FROM absent à l'emplacement prévu**

I can't figure out why. What is wrong with my query ?

Comment: Which is it SQL Server or Oracle the error message is pointing to Oracle, you using the correct connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORA-... is an Oracle error message. And Oracle doesn't have top, you need to use fetch first n rows only

I'd say you are using T-SQL language for an Oracle DB